# Explain why the Wrong Output Happened?

Tags: java, arrays, io, java.util.scanner

```
public class ArrayIntro
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a;
        a=new int[10];
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();  
        }
        for(int e:a)
        {
            System.out.print(e+' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Input:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Output:33343536373839404142

Its mean it added 32 to each number

Comment: Try `" "` instead of `' '` - the `char` data type does crazy stuff when you add it to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with below code.

As you are printing sout inside for loop, it's printing sum of number and Space( **`' '`**). And space have ASCII value of 32, so you are able to see every element with added value of 32.

For [**ASCII Or Unicode**](https://mathbits.com/JavaBitsNotebook/LibraryMethods/CharacterMethods.html) you can refer this link, it will help you.

Simply you put something like this **`System.out.print(new Integer(' '));`**, it will print 32.

If you want to add space only then go with double quote.
**`System.out.print(e+" ");`**.

Single quote consider as character and charater added with Integer will summing up with their ASCII code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a;
        a=new int[10];
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();  
        }
        for(int e:a)
        {
            System.out.print(e+" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.But why it added those?

Comment: This line behave like this `System.out.print(e+' ');` 1+32 ,2+32 ,3+32 as ASCII of space is 32.

Comment: Instead of single quote you can use double quote like this `  System.out.println(e+ " ");`

Comment: I don't feel this answer adequately explains the difference between adding with `char` values, and adding with `String` values.  Moreover, the frequent mentions of ASCII are very misleading - most Java `char` values don't have ASCII representations at all, so this answer wouldn't apply to them.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem his question is with why it's adding 32 with every digit. So simple answer to it like, when you put single quoted space it's consider as space character and in java  `space character ('  ')` has **32 UNICODE value** and that's why it's adding 32 with every number.

Comment: And regarding difference between String and Character already try to explain in answer.

Comment: I don't think you _have_ explained the difference between `String` and `char` - your answer doesn't actually contain the word `String` or the word `char` anywhere.  Since the cause of the OP's problem is the difference between a `String` literal and a `char` literal, this is kind of important.  Without mentioning this, you haven't answered the question.  Also, you keep talking about ASCII, but Java doesn't use ASCII at all.  That makes this answer wrong.  Hari's answer, although it incorrectly mentions ASCII, gets to the crux of the matter - the difference between `char` and `String` literals.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, ' ' is a character in ASCII and the value of it is 32. So, as far as I know, you might want it the just print directly so you can just replace ' ' with " ". Always remember that single quotes are for characters and double quotes are for strings.

For your answer you can just do this:`System.out.print(e+" ");`

Instead of this: `System.out.print(e+' ');`

Answer (score 0):

In short, to fix your program, you need to use `" "` (with double quotes) instead of `' '`.

The issue is that the `+` operator has two different meanings in Java.

- If either of the operands is a `String`, then `+` means "concatenate these two operands together".  If the other operand is not a `String`, then it will have to be converted somehow, and there are some rules around how to do this.
- If neither operand is a `String`, then `+` means "add these two operands together" - that is, they are treated as numbers.  They can be added as `double` values, `float` values, `long` values or `int` values, depending on the data types.  But if they are `short`, `byte` or `char`, they will be treated as `int`.  This is called binary numeric promotion, and is explained in detail in the Java Language Specification.

Now in Java, single quotes are used to delimit a `char` literal.  So when you write `e + ' '`, you're adding an `int` to a `char`.  This is addition - the `char` is treated as an `int`, and the operands are added as numbers.  The number corresponding to   is 32, since that's the numeric value in the character encoding that Java uses, which is something like UTF-16.  Contrary to some other answers on this page, it's *not* ASCII.

Double quotes are used to delimit a `String` literal.  So if you write `e + " "`, the operands are an `int` and a `String`.  That means you're not adding any more, but concatenating.  The `int` is converted to a `String` first, then concatenated to `" "`, which will give you the result you're expecting.